# Extract Max or Min Value from Point File Attribute and then Add XY Coordinate

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, extract

I have created a Point dataset by using the Saga routine 'Convert Lines to Points'. This produces the following look and attribute table:
[image: Points in QGIS]

[image: Attribute Table]

Can anyone advise on how I can extract the maximum value from each 'ID' set (red polygon in image) and then add the correct XY position of that single (maximum value) point?

What I want to end up with is a list / table showing only the maximum value and XY coordinate for each cross line of points.

There are over 350 unique 'ID' sets within the attribute table, so the end table / file should contain 350 maximum values and coordinates.

Update... I have a shapefile of the data in question but I can't work out how to add it to this question! Can anyone advise please?

Comment: Can you share your data, at least a sample? Like this, it's not clear to me what you have - and what you want to achieve: what should your final goal look like?

Comment: I have a file to share with you but can't work out how to add it to the question or response (sorry, I am new to this forum). I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You can't post files here, you must use an external fileshsring service and post the link here.

Comment: I have now uploaded the sample file at the following link...https://we.tl/t-vX35UYZBrY

Comment: The final goal would be to have the initial dataset analysed to extract from each cross line of points the maximum value (height) with its associated XY coordinate. This dataset would then be a line providing the highest depth values.

Comment: I downloaded your data, and it seems that my expression works (with QGIS 3.20). However, I'm still not sure if I understood your final goal. Can you give a concrete hint: what should be the final output for the points with ID=1? I get the maximum X-value, that is -22.691. Is that what you want?

Comment: The end goal / result would be to extract the single maximum height from each 'ID' set of lines and then add the relevant XY values, i.e. from all the lines with an FID of '1' extract the max value, and from all the lines with FID of '2' extract the max value etc. and then add the correct XY value of that point. The final listing will just be max Z and XY.

Comment: So -22.691 is the maximum X-value you want to get for ID=1 or not? Just to know if the solution proposed works or not.

Comment: Correct. -22.691 would be the value to extract and then add the associated XY coordinates of this specific point.

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression in field calculator. Be aware: [`array_max`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-max) works only with [QGIS versions 3.18 or higher](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays):

```
array_max(
    array_foreach (
        array_filter(  
            map_akeys( attributes( )), 
            left (@element,1)='X'
        ),
        eval(@element)
))
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but it results in an error... 'Expression is invalid'. I have tried both the text from above and also the text within your screen grab.

Comment: What QGIS version do you use?  Some parts of the expression work with newer versions only: `array_max` since QGIS 3.18: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays

Comment: I am currently using 3.16, so thanks for the response - I'll look at upgrading and testing the expression